# What anthologies might offer introductions to moral philosophy?

Tags: ethics, metaethics

After reading the essay "What I believe" by Bertrand Russell, I became very interested in learning more about moral philosophy.

What I am now looking for is a collection of writings by different philosophers so that I could get a broader view of moral philosophy and then perhaps move on to some specific theories.

I should perhaps add that I do not have a university education in philosophy (I am a physicist by training) and thus I am essentially an autodidact (aside from some high school education on the subject).

Comment: You can start with [Moral Cognitivism vs. Non-Cognitivism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-cognitivism/) : it has bibliography and reference to some on-line resources.

Comment: You can try with John Skorupski (editor), [The Routledge Companion to Ethics](https://books.google.it/books?id=wYHFBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2010).

Comment: Both (well, the second is incredibly comprehensive) sound very good references. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

As I see it, to progress forward (and not get tangled up in the jargon), you need to first decide whether Moral Realism (Moral Reality) rings true for you or not. Take things a step at a time - and that's the first step in my view.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this? In short you think it's not worth approaching the subject as a whole but already from one side (Moral Realism) or another (Moral subjectivism and similar)?

Comment: Not quite. What I am saying is that to discover an answer which 'rings true' for the individual - as distinct from just studying & understanding the subject - that individual must decide which path to take : moral realism or not. That requires cutting through the crap of jargon and sophistry, and that's like swimming in treacle.